# Should we use flask-migrate in the init_app function or separately in our run script?

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I am reading through Grinberg's Flask Development 2nd ed., and I have a question about flask migrate & a "large app structure".

Previously, I had used migrate like any other extension, like

```py
# __init__.py
...
from flask_migrate import Migrate

...

migrate = Migrate()

...
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    ...
    return app
```

This is suggested in the [Flask-Migrate docs](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#command-reference), but I understand it is obviously not the only way to do it. And then I had an entrypoint script, or root-level application script, which I call with `python run.py`:

```py
# root-level application script
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In the Flask Web Development book however, which walks through the [Flasky app](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky), Miguel shows on page 93 a setup where migrate is actually imported and initialised with `app` and `db` in the **root-level application script** and NOT the app-level `__init__.py` file. What I mean is this:

```
flasky
├── app/
│   ├── api/
│   ├── auth/
│   ├── main/
│   ├── static/
│   ├── templates/
│   └── __init__.py  # App-level init script
├── migrations/
└── flasky.py  # Root-level application script
```

There is not an explanation as to why this approach was chosen. I was previously running my app by calling the root-level application script, not using the `flask run` CLI command. When I tried having migrate in this root level, it of course was not recognised because I had not exported `FLASK_APP=run.py`, so the `flask` CLI command was unaware of `db` or `migrate`. This means I would need to change how I run my application.

My question then is, what might be the reasoning for putting migrate in the root level app script vs in my `__init__.py` file's `create_app()` function? Given that Miguel has written the extension he has decided on this for a reason but I am not sure why this extension is treated differently. Could it be something to do with separating the database-related code away from the rest of the application code?

Sorry if this is not the right place, but I can't exactly make an issue on the flasky github because it is just a question and not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are valid. The reason one may want to initialize Flask-Migrate separately is that conceptually this is an extension that only affects the CLI, unlike most other extensions which are used by the server while running. But this is a very minor distinction, these days I initialize it along with all other extensions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So if you initialize it with the other extensions, how are you able to then access it with the CLI, given that an app instance is not created in that module? I did swap it into the app script as you demonstrated in the book, but I quite like the idea of having it with all of the other extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the definition of Flask-Migrate from the Python File with the `create_app()` function, which is the `__init__.py`. So, to modify the code you sent:

```py
# __init__.py
...
from flask_migrate import Migrate

...

# migrate = Migrate()

...
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    # migrate.init_app(app, db)
    ...
    return app
```

And then, modify `run.py`:

```py
# root-level application script
from app import create_app
from flask_migrate import migrate

app = create_app()
Migrate(app, db)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run()
    pass
```

This will make the Flask CLI work and accept <kbd>db</kbd> commands. Hope this was helpful, if not please leave a comment below. Good luck!